# mysql append char with integer return 0 in function

Tags: mysql, sql, function

I have created this function in mysql and i want result with cocated values like `(1,0,-2,-1)` but instead its giving result `0`

```
DROP Function IF EXISTS get_preorder_status;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE Function get_preorder_status(loc_pre_order_id int) RETURNS INT(10)
BEGIN     
DECLARE all_status CHAR(10) DEFAULT '';
DECLARE temp_status INT(2);
DECLARE n INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;

SELECT  count(*) into n
FROM pre_order_detail
WHERE pre_order_id = loc_pre_order_id;

WHILE i<n DO 
SELECT  customer_response_status into temp_status
FROM pre_order_detail
WHERE pre_order_id = loc_pre_order_id LIMIT i,1;
SET all_status = CONCAT(all_status,', ',CAST(temp_status AS CHAR));
SET i = i + 1;
END WHILE;`

RETURN all_status;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

all_status is char type variable but temp_status is INT and i want final result with concat those integer values in one string type value with comma saparated

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Your function is returning an `int`.  Try having it return a character type.

In other words, the string is being converted to an int when returned.

The logic can more simply be written as:

```
SELECT group_concat(customer_response_status) into temp_status
FROM pre_order_detail
WHERE pre_order_id = loc_pre_order_id ;
```

No need for a loop.

Comment: Oh Thanks. i was fool i did not notices that return type

Comment: Yeah i need loop because this is relational database for one to many mapping, with table `pre_order` and `pre_order_detail` and i need cancat status of all child table data